# How to add scroll to the column in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a screen with multiple widgets in a single column. I got the error. And then I have updated the height for the containers in the columns then the screen is not scrolled as it has some fixed size.

Then I moved from columns to `ListView` but still, my widgets do not scroll.

```
  new ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[

            // Author information
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height * .075,
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10.00, right: 10.00),
              child: new Row(

                children: <Widget>[

                  new CircleAvatar(

                    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF535386),
                    foregroundColor: new Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
                    backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(
                        _feed.authorImageUrl),
                    radius: 30.00,
                    child: new Text(
                        _feed.authorName.substring(0, 1)
                            .toUpperCase()),
                  ),

                  new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 5.00, top: 2.00, left: 5.00),
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                            .start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            _feed.authorName,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            softWrap: true,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,

                            ),
                          ),
                          new Text(_feed.dateTime,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                        ],
                      )),

                ],

              ),
            ),

            // Title

            new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 10.00, left: 10.00),
              child: new Text(
                _feed.title, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
            ),

            // content

            new Container(
              child: new Text(
                _feed.content, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Use a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I used `ListView` also it not working. Please check the above code.

Comment: Is the content higher than the list? Try enabling https://flutter.io/debugging/#visual-debugging `debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;`

Comment: Yes, I am loading the complete forum feed in this `Text()` so for some feeds the content is higher. This forum application. The complete forum post and its comments will be loaded on this screen. That's why I am looking scroll.

Comment: I think the MediaQuery is causing your problem. What effect are you trying to achieve? Using `Expanded` might be a better way to achieve a proportional layout if that's what your after.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `ListView` seems to be fine, but I'm guessing it's wrapped inside a fixed size Widget as `Column` or `Row` (the yellow and black error means that the content is bigger than the available space), so you should wrap the `ListView` inside an `Expanded` widget like this:

```
new Expanded(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        //Your content
      ],
    )
)
```